# How do I make my D3 map load faster?

Tags: d3.js

I have created a world map using this D3 tutorial:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

However, it takes about 5-10 seconds to load on the page. My guess is I'm adding much more detail than I need and that I need to create a JSON file which will draw my country polygons with much fewer data points.

Again, I'm guessing, but maybe I need to do this at the point of creating my GeoJSON file:

```
ogr2ogr \
  -f GeoJSON \
  -where "ADM0_A3 NOT IN ('ATA')" \
  subunits.json \
  ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
```

Any ideas how to make my map load much faster? Thanks.

Comment: Not knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve, this might not suit your needs, but on http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/ they have less detailed maps, with a smaller scale. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, but I need to generate my own map from the source file in the code above: ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp

Comment: What I meant is, you can achieve the same thing with another less detailed data set (formatted the same way, but with less details). But that might not be suitable for what you try to achieve.

Comment: I've found the medium sized equivalent map. Thanks.